# I want to create a condition and post using axios at React.js

Tags: reactjs, json

In the Data of the API document below,

**If "brightness_value" is larger than 0,
I want to set mode to "turn_on".**

**If brightness_value is 0,
I want to set mode to "turn_off".**

Is that possible to implement?

If so, how?

**API Document**

```
Method: POST
URL: xxx.com
Data:

{
"time_start":"16:20",
"time_end":"16:21",
    "mode":{
        "mode":"turn_off", //or “turn_on”
        "rgb_color":[255,255,255],
        "brightness":50
    }
}
```

**My React.js code**

```
  const [brightness_value, setBrightnessValue] = useState();

  const setSchedule = async(data) => {
    await axios.post('xxx.com',
      {
        time_start: "16:20",
        time_end: "16:21",
        mode: {
          mode: "turn_off", 
          rgb_color: [255,255,255], 
          brightness: brightness_value,
        }
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('Scheduled!');   
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Missed Schedule!');
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ternary operator for this:

```js
mode: {
         mode: brightness_value === 0 ? "turn_off":"turn_on",  
          rgb_color: [255,255,255], 
          brightness: brightness_value,
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. I follow you but it always "turn_off"... For example, now the Brightness is "59". It should be "turn_on". I don't know why...

Comment: sorry my mistake. it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
mode: {
         mode: Number.parseInt(brightness_value) === 0 ? "turn_off":"turn_on",  
          rgb_color: [255,255,255], 
          brightness: brightness_value,
        }
```

It should do the job.